# Issue with setFirestoreSettings

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to both Android and Firestore and haven't been able to figure out how to set a Firestore object's settings. Here is the code I've been using:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

FirebaseFirestore firestore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).build();
    firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

}
```

But this gives an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseFirestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only call setFirestoreSettings() before calling any other methods on a FirebaseFirestore object.
```

However, this error only occurs when I use setPersistanceEnabled(false) and/or setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).

If I use setPersistanceEnabled(true) and/or setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(false), the app works.

If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 6):

You probably do some DB operations before this code, from a different activity or a service.

Any DB operation initializes Firestore with the default settings, setPersistanceEnabled(true) and setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(false). When you subsequently set the same settings, it works fine. When you trying to change settings it throws an exception.

In my case the settings were set in the main activity, but when a different activity was called via a shortcut and performed DB operation, starting main activity after that caused an exception.

Comment: You are correct, I cannot find any clear reference to add an inline check to see if the settings are already set. Any ideas how to get around this? (even if you set the settings in your first/main activity say ActivityA, what if you have a deep link to ActivityB which calls on Firestore and then user back navigates to A? Only way around this is filtering all app opens through a splash activity that sets the setting, but it'd be more convenient with an inline check.)

Comment: You don't need to know if settings were already intiialized. You can initialize them again, just make sure that it is the same settings. Write a common initialization  code and call it from every activity before DB operations.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose it isn't changing the setting if it's calling the same one each time. I was just trying to avoid applying the settings in every activity. Thanks.